# Crystal Report dataset with same column names from multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I've two tables - Order_Header and Product and both these have a column called Discount. I've added the Discount from Product table to my dataset and run the report with no problems. However, I need the Discount field from Order_Header as well. I cannot add this to the dataset because the column with same name exists. How can I achieve that?

I tried to use `Order_Header.Discount` but it didn't work. Any ideas

This is the Discount column I've used in the dataset before.

```
    <xs:element name="Discount" 
msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnDiscount" 
msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Discount" 
msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="DiscountColumn" 
msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Discount" type="xs:double"
 minOccurs="0" />
```

Comment: are you using query or xml as input to crystal reports?

Comment: @Siva.. I'm using a strongly typed dataset for the elements I want in the report and using a query in an .aspx page to fill the data into these elements.